# Django model validation which uses a ManyToMany field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-validation

I have a model like this:

```py
class Offer(models.Model):
    condition_products = models.ManyToManyField(
        "shop.Product",
        blank=True,
        help_text="User needs to own at least one of these products.",
    )
    condition_owned_after = models.DateField(
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        help_text="User needs to own at least one products after this date.",
        verbose_name="Owned after date",
    )
```

It's for a webshop where we can create offers with certain conditions. One of the conditions is that the user needs to already own one or more products, and a second condition is that this products needs to be owned after a certain date.

I want to add validation to the model so that `condition_owned_after` can only be filled in when `condition_product_variants` is not None. But when I try to access `condition_product_variants` in the `clean` method I get a ValueError from Django.

```py
class Offer(models.Model):
    # ...

    def clean(self):
        if self.condition_owned_after and not self.condition_products.all():
            raise ValidationError(
                {
                    "condition_owned_after": "Cannot set condition_owned_after without also setting condition_products"
                }
            )

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.full_clean()
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

This results in the following error:

`ValueError: "<Offer: Offer object (None)>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used`

I understand the error, but I don't understand how to work around it. How can I validate my model, when the validation depends on the value of this M2M field?

I know that I can create a `ModelForm` and assign it to the `ModelAdmin` and do the validation there, so at least adding items via the admin UI is validated. But that doesn't validate models getting created or saved outside of the admin UI of course.

Comment: If you create an object, then the m2m field is *not* yet created, and since the object has no primary key, using `self.condition_products.all()` is not possible. But even if it was, you *don't* save an `Offer` in case you only manipulate the m2m fiield, since that is a separate table, so even if that would wokr, it does not guarantee the condition.

Comment: Yes I understand why it is happening. The question is how I add validation to the model.